# Nested Input field not saving when DOM loses focus

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, kendo-ui

I have an input box located on a "card" that is deeply nested in multiple classes. I want to be able to allow a user to save their input when the input box loses focus, essentially allowing a click anywhere else on the card to save the current value of the input box. Currently this behavior works only if I click completely outside the card and list of cards area. How can I make it so clicking anywhere outside of the input field allows for the current value to be saved?  I am using jQuery, Kendo, and typescript

Comment: We need to see some code to help you. You must already have a lost focus / blur event of some sort if clicking away sometimes triggers your save? How is that wired up and on what element / control? What elements are wrapping the input box?

Comment: @NigelK 
`<div class="card-values">
     <span class="edit-card-value" >
         <input data-bind='value: card.Value, attr: { data-card-id: card.ID }, events: { blur: saveSingleCard }'/>
       </span>`. Currently, if I click anywhere else on the card, nothing happens, however clicking outside of the cards allows for the saveSingleCard event to run. I have tried with JQuery to attach a selector specifically for the input field and confirmed that it does return the `<input>`, but the span and div that wrap the element seem to be included when attempting to target only the input element

Comment: I've tried that with some text either side of the span. For me, the event fires when I click that text. Might it be the classes card-value and edit-card-value? Do they do anything like blocking pointer events? When you click outside the box but still within the card does the box actually lose focus or is the cursor still in it?

Comment: I think you're right @NigelK, I wasnt able to resolve this but I appreciate you pointing me in the direction of it being blocked by some CSS, we think that is the case, I will update you when I have found the solution

Comment: @NigelK We finally found a solution for this, and it wasnt actually a class issue. Clicking outside the input but inside the card wasn’t triggering blur/lost focus because the kendo Sortable component, we were using to provide drag and drop functionality was preventing the action. To resolve this, the kendo Sortable component is being destroyed when an input is in "Edit mode" we created and restored when the Editing is complete. Kudos to my leader for figuring this one out, I was looking completely in the wrong direction! Thank you for your advice!

Comment: No problem. Glad you got there in the end.